# Cats' Monoid instance throws exception when merging Maps of Arrays

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, category-theory, monoids

I defined a Monoid instance for `Map[Int, Array[Int]]` and tried to use it to merge a list of such maps:

```scala
import cats.Monoid
import cats.implicits._

implicit val m: Monoid[Map[Int, Array[Int]]] = Monoid[Map[Int, Array[Int]]]

List(
  Map(
    (0 -> Array(8, 9))
  ),
  Map(
    (0 -> Array(10))
  ),
  Map(
    (1 -> Array(30))
  ),
).foldMap(identity)
```

I would expect the output to be this:

```scala
Map(
  (0 -> Array(8, 9, 10),
  (1 -> Array(30),
)
```

However, the code throws the following excpetion:

```
[error] java.lang.NullPointerException
[error]         at cats.instances.ListInstances$$anon$1.foldMap(list.scala:74)
[error]         at cats.instances.ListInstances$$anon$1.foldMap(list.scala:16)
[error]         at cats.Foldable$Ops.foldMap(Foldable.scala:31)
[error]         at cats.Foldable$Ops.foldMap$(Foldable.scala:31)
[error]         at cats.Foldable$ToFoldableOps$$anon$5.foldMap(Foldable.scala:31)
```

I tried using `.reduce(_ |+| _)` or `m.combineAll` instead of `.foldMap(identity)`, with the same result.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh and in case that's relevant: I'm using `cats-core` version `2.1.0`

Comment: This line:`implicit val m: Monoid[Map[Int, Array[Int]]] = Monoid[Map[Int, Array[Int]]]` produces a cyclic reference. Because the `apply` method in the `Monoid` companion object returns an implicit value, which is what you defined. This results in a `null` _(you can check it using a **REPL**)_. I would tell you that you only need to remove that line, but then it will fail with an `could not find implicit value for parameter B: cats.Monoid[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Array[Int]]]``this is dues **cats** does not provide a `Monoid` for `Arrays` _(because of mutability)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez you're right, I was able to achieve the desired result after removing the culprit line and replacing Arrays with Lists. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your code work, you'd only need to provide proper Monoid for an array:

```
//we also need ClassTag because we don't know type yet and arrays aren't generic
implicit def arrayMonoid[T: ClassTag]: Monoid[Array[T]] = new Monoid[Array[T]] {
    override def empty: Array[T] = Array[T]()

    override def combine(x: Array[T], y: Array[T]): Array[T] = x ++ y
}
```

Cats library doesn't provide **Monoid** for arrays by default.

Comment: That worked too, thanks. Though I wonder, doesn't defining a Monoid instance for arrays violate some category theory laws? In the comments under my original question, @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez mentionned arrays are not monoids because of their mutability

Comment: @Bertrand I am not sure, I would guess would be no perse. But, technically speaking, since you can modify the elements at any moment, then equality doesn't hold. Also, functional programming embraces immutability to reason about code. I would just use a different data type like **List**, but if you require **Arrays** for any reason, and this is final code that won't be exposed as a library, you are free to define instances for the types you want, even if they break some laws.

Comment: Actually, as far as I checked this monoid holds all laws (right and left identity and associativity), so it's lawful. But as Luis noticed Array is just wrapper for Java's array, which is always mutable. If you need immutable array-like structure, you could try **ArraySeq**, which was introduced in Scala 2.13.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I'm sure some fanatics would be outraged if I defined a Monoid instance for mutable Arrays :) Also, the code I'm writing may end up in a library so I guess I'll just use a Vector. Thanks!

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik looks like ArraySeq is so new that Cats does not provide a Monoid instance for it yet (neither does it for IndexedSeq). Of course since this one is immutable I could write my own Monoid instance for it, but is there a compelling reason for using ArraySeq instead of Vector? (I guess I need to read up on ArraySeq)

Comment: @Bertrand If you are not going to be prepending values to it, an **ArraySeq** should be faster than **Vector**. But as always, do proper benchmarking to be sure.

Comment: @Bertrand [**FYI**](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/pull/3273).

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez nice!